# Cannot assign background image

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-tsx

I am trying to assign a background image with styled components to the whole website. This project is in React and typescript
Component

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import bImage from './assets/background.jpg';



const Background = styled.html`
background-image: url(${bImage});
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

`

function FirstPage() : JSX.Element {
    return  <Background/>

    
}

export default FirstPage;
```

index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import FirstPage from './PortfolioIntro';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <FirstPage />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put your `background.png` file in your public folder and then access it like that:

```
const Background = styled.html`
background-image: url(/background.png);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
`
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Did that, nothing is rendering

Comment: Maybe try something like `styled.div` instead of `styled.html`

Comment: If I use it as a div, I have some top padding and left padding, the image is not covering the whole page if that makes sense

Comment: I added margin -10px and I fixed this, but if I set the height to 100% the image dissappears again

Comment: Try to remove the padding of the `<body>` tag

Comment: tried setting padding and margin to 0 and doesn't do anything

Comment: it's strange that if I create the styling in a css file rather than using the styled components, the background image fits perfectly